# Angular css style is not changing

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I have:

```
  <ion-item [ngClass]="{'bgred': correctAnswerFirst}">
  </ion-item>
```

and:

```
page-quizpageloop {
    .bgred{
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

In typescript I set the boolean value:

```
if(this.correctAnswer==1){
      this.correctAnswerFirst = true;
}
```

But the background-color does not change, when the boolean value is set to `true`

Full code:

HTML:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar hideBackButton="true">
    <ion-title>Quiz</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <h4 id="page2-heading1" style="color:#000000;">
    Question {{currentQuestionNumber}}: {{questionStr}}
  </h4>

  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="answers" formControlName="listOptions">

      <ion-item [class.bgred]="correctAnswerFirst">
        <ion-radio value="answer1" (ionSelect)="processSelectedAnswer(1)"></ion-radio>
        <ion-label>{{answer1}}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
  </form>

</ion-content>
```

Controller:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-quizpageloop',
  templateUrl: 'quizpageloop.html'
})

export class QuizPageLoop {

  correctAnswerFirst: boolean;

  showNextQuestion() {
     if(this.correctAnswer==1){
        this.correctAnswerFirst = true;
     }
     this.wait(3000);
  }
```

and full scss is:

```
page-quizpageloop {
    .bgred{
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

I have debugged the application and I come to the point `this.correctAnswerFirst = true;` the variable is set to `true`, but the color does not change...

Comment: Try     `[class.bgred]="correctAnswerFirst" `. If this doesn't work, please provide your full template, scss & controller

Comment: Also without `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` on the controller, `page-quizpageloop` will also not work and is not needed

Comment: if `page-quizpageloop` is your component selector (`<page-quizpageloop></page-quizpageloop>`), you should remove it and leave just `.bgred {...}`. If you must have it then access it with `:host` selector in your CSS/SCSS

Comment: @Stefan no its not working. I have added full code in the question.

Comment: @farahm I've removed my answer, my method is deprecated. Maybe this sould help, https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Answer (score 0):

In this

```
if(this.correctAnswer==1){
  this.correctAnswerFirst = true;
```

}

```
this.correctAnswer is undefined and so if condition fails and this.correctAnswerFirst is not set to true
```

Comment: Well, in the constructor I do `this.correctAnswerFirst = false;` I did not mention this in the code because I wanted to keep the code short in the question

Comment: I have debugged the application and I come to the point `this.correctAnswerFirst = true;` the variable is set to true, but the color does not change...